# Can ffmpeg copy parts from an rmvb file without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to fast copy parts from an rmvb file without re-encoding. This command works fine with mp4 files but not with rmbv (I dropped start time and duration here) :

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy output
```

when I use it with rmvb like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.mp4
```

I get this error:

> [mp4 @ 00bb8980] Could not find tag for codec rv40 in stream #0, codec
>   not curre ntly supported in container Could not write header for
>   output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invali d argument
>   Stream mapping:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1
>   (copy)

I also tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 2.rmvb
```

and got this error:

> [NULL @ 04748980] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2.rmvb'
>   2.rmvb: Invalid argument

I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k 1.mp4
```

and got this error:

> [mp4 @ 046e0020] Could not find tag for codec rv40 in stream #0, codec
>   not curre ntly supported in container Could not write header for
>   output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invali d argument Error
>   initializing output stream 0:1 -- [aac @ 046e1bc0] Qavg: nan
>   Conversion failed!

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108323/converting-real-media-with-ffmpeg):
but the solution does not work for me.. After many trials, this is the command that worked (and took too long time):

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c:v libx264 -b:a 32k output.mp4
```

But I do not want to re-encode the file. Any solution?

Edit:
I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.mkv
```

> ffmpeg version N-86447-gfeb13ae Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)   configuration: --enable-gpl
>   --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth -- enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls
>   --enable-iconv
>   --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
>   -enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx  --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
>   -libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib   libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100   libavcodec     57. 98.100 /
>   57. 98.100   libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100   libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100   libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100   libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101   libswresample   2.  8.100 / 
>   2.  8.100   libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100 [rm @ 033a7520] Invalid stream index 2 for index at pos 206099254 Input #0, rm, from
>   '1.rmvb':   Metadata:
>       title           : ArabSeed.CoM
>       author          : ArabSeed.CoM
>       copyright       : ArabSeed.CoM
>       comment         :
>       ASMRuleBook     : #($Bandwidth >= 0),Stream0Bandwidth = 64082, Stream1Bandwi dth = 285918;
>       Audiences       : Easy RealMedia Tool's Audience;
>       audioMode       : music
>       Creation Date   : 4/22/2010 4:31:14
>       Description     : This File is Created by Easy RealMedia Tools@!
>       Email           : rick@redcheek.net
>       Generated By    : Easy RealMedia Tools V1.8x
>       HomeWeb         : http://redcheek.net
>       Keywords        : ArabSeed.CoM
>       Modification Date: 4/22/2010 4:31:14
>       videoMode       : normal   Duration: 01:16:35.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 358 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: cook (cook / 0x6B6F6F63), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/ s
>       Stream #0:1: Video: rv40 (RV40 / 0x30345652), yuv420p, 720x408, 280 kb/s, 25  fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc Output #0, matroska, to
>   '1.mkv':   Metadata:
>       title           : ArabSeed.CoM
>       author          : ArabSeed.CoM
>       copyright       : ArabSeed.CoM
>       comment         :
>       ASMRuleBook     : #($Bandwidth >= 0),Stream0Bandwidth = 64082, Stream1Bandwi dth = 285918;
>       Audiences       : Easy RealMedia Tool's Audience;
>       audioMode       : music
>       Creation Date   : 4/22/2010 4:31:14
>       Description     : This File is Created by Easy RealMedia Tools@!
>       Email           : rick@redcheek.net
>       Generated By    : Easy RealMedia Tools V1.8x
>       HomeWeb         : http://redcheek.net
>       Keywords        : ArabSeed.CoM
>       Modification Date: 4/22/2010 4:31:14
>       videoMode       : normal
>       encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
>       Stream #0:0: Video: rv40 (RV40 / 0x30345652), yuv420p, 720x408, q=2-31, 280 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
>       Stream #0:1: Audio: cook ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 44100 Hz, ster eo, fltp, 64 kb/s Stream mapping:   Stream #0:1 -> #0:0
>   (copy)   Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [matroska @ 05228980] The Matroska muxer does not yet support muxing
>   cook av_interleaved_write_frame(): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg,
>   patches welcome Error writing trailer of 1.mkv: Not yet implemented in
>   FFmpeg, patches welcome frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB
>   time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=   0.0kbits /s speed= 148x video:2kB
>   audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ove
>   rhead: unknown Conversion failed!

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.avi

ffmpeg version N-86447-gfeb13ae Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavcodec     57. 98.100 / 57. 98.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[rm @ 00077520] Invalid stream index 2 for index at pos 206099254
Input #0, rm, from '1.rmvb':
  Metadata:
    title           : ArabSeed.CoM
    author          : ArabSeed.CoM
    copyright       : ArabSeed.CoM
    comment         :
    ASMRuleBook     : #($Bandwidth >= 0),Stream0Bandwidth = 64082, Stream1Bandwi
dth = 285918;
    Audiences       : Easy RealMedia Tool's Audience;
    audioMode       : music
    Creation Date   : 4/22/2010 4:31:14
    Description     : This File is Created by Easy RealMedia Tools@!
    Email           : rick@redcheek.net
    Generated By    : Easy RealMedia Tools V1.8x
    HomeWeb         : http://redcheek.net
    Keywords        : ArabSeed.CoM
    Modification Date: 4/22/2010 4:31:14
    videoMode       : normal
  Duration: 01:16:35.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 358 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: cook (cook / 0x6B6F6F63), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/
s
    Stream #0:1: Video: rv40 (RV40 / 0x30345652), yuv420p, 720x408, 280 kb/s, 25
 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operat
ion not permitted
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a `rv40` stream to test with, but you should be able to mux into MKV, AVI, and RM.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.mkv
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.rm
ffmpeg -i 1.rmvb -c copy 1.avi
```

Comment: Thanks Mulvya, but it does not work. I've editted my question to add the full ffmpeg response. Hope you can discover what is wrong with the ffmpeg version or video file format (I of course tried different rmvb files).

Comment: You didn't mention you have `cook` audio. Did you try `.rm`? You can still use MKV or AVI if you re-encode the audio.

Comment: @Gyan : `.rm` works, but `.rm` isn't needed. You said: `You can still use MKV or AVI if you re-encode the audio.`, Can you provide the cmd? Thanks.

Comment: Change `-c copy` to `-c:v copy`